# Отправка данных через форму

Tags: html

На странице есть много блоков, в каждом из них пользователь заполняет поля. Все эти данные отправляются на одну страницу. Вопрос- Что-бы передать данные на страницу, надо все 200 строк html завернуть в форму или как ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если на чистом html, то в форму завернуть все поля для ввода (input,textarea).

Comment: ну а не чего, что внутри нее получится много элементов левых ?